# populating a constexpr array using C++17

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, constexpr

I'm trying to initialize a `constexpr` array using `C++17` via the following:

```
template <size_t N>
struct CStr
{
    static constexpr std::array<int, N> getArr()
    {
        std::array<int, N> a;
        for (auto idx = 0; idx < a.size(); ++idx)
        {
            a[idx] = idx * idx;
        }
        return a;
    }
    static constexpr auto arr { getArr()};
};


int main()
{
    for (const auto &el : CStr<10>::arr)
    {
        std::cout << el << std::endl;
    }
}
```

However this results in the following compile error about `getArr` not being a `constexpr` function. Can someone help explain why ?

```
<source>: In instantiation of 'constexpr const std::array<int, 10> CStr<10>::arr':
<source>:18:27:   required from 'struct CStr<10>'
<source>:24:35:   required from here
<source>:18:39: error: 'static constexpr std::array<int, N> CStr<N>::getArr() [with long unsigned int N = 10]' called in a constant expression
   18 |     static constexpr auto arr { getArr()};
      |                                 ~~~~~~^~
<source>:9:41: note: 'static constexpr std::array<int, N> CStr<N>::getArr() [with long unsigned int N = 10]' is not usable as a 'constexpr' function because:
    9 |     static constexpr std::array<int, N> getArr()
      |                                         ^~~~~~
<source>:12:9: error: 'goto' is not a constant expression
   12 |         for (auto idx = 0; idx < a.size(); ++idx)
      |         ^~~
Compiler returned: 1   |                                         ^~~~~
```

Comment: You have cut off the error message, it still continues - and contains a hilarious remark about `goto` :D

Comment: The issue disappears when you initialize `std::array<int, N> a{};`. clang has a much more intelligible error message for this case :) Also, using `-std=c++20` makes the error disappear.

Comment: This is probably https://wg21.link/p1331

Comment: Thanks dyp! Would you mind letting us know the procedure used to locate the relevant working group paper?

Comment: If I had one, I'd tell you. I googled `constexpr initialization site:open-std.org` and it was the first hit :D

Comment: W.r.t. -std=c++2a making the error disappear (w/o explicit initialization), from your answer below does it imply then that it's a bug with both clang and gcc allowing it? For example even if I stop the setting loop iteration to a.size()-1, in the process reading uninitialized memory, it seems to build fine w/ "0" being read.

Comment: For example in the InlinedVector section at the end of the paper they seem to be OK w/ reading uninitialized memory in a ```constexpr``` context

Comment: Can you give me a full example regarding both what you're doing with `a.size()-1` and the `InlinedVector`? I don't quite get what you're referring to in either case :(

Comment: I was a little confused about https://godbolt.org/z/GM1cEG compiling OK with gcc. However it turns out it does not compile with clang.. Likely a compiler bug w/ the former.

Comment: Huh, yes, very interesting!

Comment: This is really confusing, especially the mention of `goto`. Futhermore, the error was at a completely different place than shown by clang. I only found it by successively commenting out code until I found an uninitialized integer 30 lines below the line mentioned in the error (but still in the same constexpr function).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a restriction in C++ until C++20, see [Permitting trivial default initialization in constexpr contexts](https://wg21.link/p1331): You have to initialize all variables inside of a `constexpr` function. The Standard gives the following example:

C++17

```
constexpr int uninit() {
  int a;                  // error: variable is uninitialized
  return a;
}
```

C++20

```
constexpr int uninit() {
  struct { int a; } s;
  return s.a;                   // error: uninitialized read of s.a
}
```

Note that the initialization itself is OK in C++20. Reading the indeterminate value (inside the "uninitialized" object) is not OK.

---

To fix your issue, initialize the array or switch to C++20:

```
static constexpr std::array<int, N> getArr()
{
    std::array<int, N> a{}; // now initialized!
    for (auto idx = 0; idx < a.size(); ++idx)
    {
        a[idx] = idx * idx;
    }
    return a;
}
```